# Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V malfunctioning

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, copy-paste, nautilus

Sometimes, I select an item, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, browse to a folder, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, but no item is copied to the folder or some other item is copied to the folder (eg from a previous select + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

For example, while migrating all my apps to repositories, I selected an app's v0.1 folder, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, browsed to the trunk folder, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, but then nothing happened.  Or I selected an app's v0.2 folder, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, browsed to trunk folder, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and then **v0.1** was copied to the trunk folder.

What is going on? How to solve?

Comment: As a follow up comment http://community.winsupersite.com/blogs/paul/archive/2010/05/06/is-the-windows-copy-and-paste-feature-broken.aspx

Comment: I've had similar problems in Windows. Usually though, it's due to trying to copy a large image and not giving the OS enough time to process it before hitting paste in an application. I'm not sure why this is happening to you though, as I'm 99% sure files/folders aren't copied the same way that Photoshop copies images. Does this happen when copying small files? I would just use `cp` to copy from the terminal.

Comment: thanks for clarifying and focusing your question, that's much better.  reopening.  i've also edited the post for grammar and to add whitespace and formatting for readability (paragraphs rock).

Answer (score 0):

`nothing happened` & later `v0.1 was copied to the trunk folder` indicates that the copy is successful but delayed. I'm just sharing a tool that has been useful to me up until today : [Teracopy](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy)

Recalling what I understand technically from Teracopy documentation (a looong time ago..), (behind the scene) a file handlers 'DO' the copy-pasting, when we hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and Explorer will update itself much-much later (much later than typing `dir` in `cmd`).

Although Teracopy key features is to resume interrupted transfer. In ur case u may have a chance to actually observe what actually happens when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is pressed. I suspect, it can be 2 issues :

1. the (windows built in) handlers doesn't do the job right.
2. Or one/both of the volume/disk have a very slow transfer rate.

However, this is my recommended solution (for u to try) : Install Teracopy.

Please share if it works/understandable/not. ( :